# Hoffman's exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question of the book Linear Algebra of Kenneth Hoffman.

Let $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space and let $B=\{\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}\}$ be a base for $V$. Let $<,>$ be  an inner product on $V$. If $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n}$ are any scalars, show that there is exactly one vector $\alpha$ in $V$ such that $<\alpha, \alpha_{j}>=c_{j}$, $j=1,\ldots, n$.

I think the following: Let be $\alpha=c_{1}\alpha_{1}+\ldots+c_{j}\alpha_{j}+\ldots+c_{n}\alpha_{n}$. This element exists and is unique. On the other hand,

$<\alpha, \alpha_{j}>=<c_{1}\alpha_{1}+\ldots+c_{j}\alpha_{j}+\ldots+c_{n}\alpha_{n}, \alpha_{j}>=c_{1}<\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{j}>+\ldots+c_{j}<\alpha_{j}, \alpha_{j}>+\ldots+c_{n}<\alpha_{n}, \alpha_{j}>$

If we have $<\alpha_{i}, \alpha_{j}>=1$, $i=j$ and $<\alpha_{i}, \alpha_{j}>=0$, $i\neq j$  ok! But if we don't have it? What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested you can orthonormalize the $\alpha_i$. Another approach is to have a system of equations. Let $\alpha=b_1\alpha_1+ \cdots +b_n\alpha_n$, then 
$<\alpha, \alpha_i>=c_i$ gives a system of equations for the $b_i$'s. This system has a unique solution iff the matrix is nonsingular. The matrix is $\{ <\alpha_i, \alpha_j>\}$ and this is nonsingular since $<,>$ is an inner product.